# Fade In & Out Animation With The Same UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I want to know whether I can create any type of animation with the same UIImageView. Whenever the user clicks a button, it will change the photo using a fade in animation.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var maximum: Int = 2
var number: Int = 0
var imageNames = ["0", "1"]

@IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Gradient
    nextButton.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.78, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0), colorTwo: UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.45, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0))

    // Drop Shadows
    nextButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    nextButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    nextButton.layer.shadowRadius = 25
    nextButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.10

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func changeImages(_ sender: Any) {
    number = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maximum)))
    mainImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(number).jpg")
}

}
```

There is no attempt of me trying to create an animation.
I was just hoping someone could help me create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to animate alpha value. make a fade in and fade out function like this :

```
 func fadeIn(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
        self.my.alpha = 0.0
    }
}

func fadeOut(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
        self.my.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

Then use it when you change your image:

```
fadeIn()
changeImages() /* your change image logic without animation */
fadeOut()
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works very effectively and perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to animate the `alpha`

```
@IBAction func changeImages(_ sender: Any) {
   number = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maximum)))
   mainImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(number).jpg")
   mainImage.alpha = 0
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
     self.mainImage.alpha = 1
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did work, you just need to add ".self" to "mainImage.apha = 1."